# On rings whose $K_0$ has nice properties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, projective-module, algebraic-k-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative, reduced ring. It can be seen that $K_0(R) \cong \mathbb Z$ as groups if and only if every finitely generated projective module is stably free. My question is, are there similar interpretations when one in the following list happens or at least some broad class of rings for which one of the following happens:

(1) $K_0(R)$ is a finitely generated, free abelian group.

(2) $K_0(R)$  is finitely generated.

(3) $K_0(R)$ is free of infinite/uncountable rank.

Comment: 3 and 4 can not happen, since there is always a surjective map $K_0(R)\to\mathbb{Z}$. 1 and 2 are very strong restrictions. For `general' rings it is not true. 5 also happens rarely, since most rings coming from geometry,  $K_0(R)$ has a non-trivial torsion free divisible group in it.

Comment: @Mohan: I just realized that there is always an injective 
map $\mathbb Z \to K_0(R) $ whenever $R$ has invariant basis number property , in particular in my case where $R$ is commutative ... which also takes care of 3 and 4 as I listed previously ...